# Non-linear regression to fit a circle shaped data

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

My data looks like this:
[image]

I have tried a neural network model to fit a curve to the data, but my error is too high. I can see that the x-y mappings are not one-to-one, as multiple x values correspond to the same y-values. However, I want to fit a curve to the data to make predictions. How can  I do that? Is the data not sufficient?

Comment: You need to model the x and y coordinates as functions of a third variable, likely time.  The data seem to be converging to a circle, so I image in the limit as time becomes large, the function will look like $<r\cos(\omega t) + x_0, r\sin(\omega t) + y_0>$

Comment: As in, in a 3D graph, time as the x co-ordinate, the x motion as the y co-ordinate and the y motion as  the  z co-ordinate?

Comment: Do you know the radius of the circle? If so, you could use the Hough Transform. Even if you don't know the radius, you could use the Hough Transform, but it will be a lot more computation, since you have to try a bunch of radii. Also, are you trying to fit only the circle, or are you also concerned about the lead-in portion?